# Install4j Installation Components issues

Tags: java, install4j

Hi I am wondering if is there any way to disable checkboxes for installation components not form components, and also if there is anyway to check if component is already installed by the install4j installer. I.e I installed one of 4 components and run again the installation and disable the component which is already installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can call

```
context.getInstallationComponentById("<ID>").setSelected(selected);
```

in a "Run script" action where `<ID>` is the ID of the installation component.

Checking for the last selection state is analogous:

```
context.getInstallationComponentById("<ID>").isSelected()
```

Comment: Okay, but I wonder about disabling the component if it was already installed. Let's say I have installation of install4j I install all components and run it for second time after finish, and these components are again available for me, is there any file or something where are located already installed components? And is there possibility to disable this checkbox if it is already installed?

Comment: You can call `context.getInstallationComponentById("<ID>").setChangeable(false)` so that the user cannot change the selection. The selected components from a previous installation are loaded by the "Load a response file" action.